# Replace XML initial tag with regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, xmldocument

I want to get all the strings starting with `<?XML` and ending with  `?>` to replace in Javascript strings.

For example
`<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` should be replaced with ''

because parsing it is resulting in an error.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/JUD0Vv/1

Comment: It works.. I did this:

function () {
  var myXML = '<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><title><line><liste><item></item></liste></line></title>';
  var foundRegex = /([\<\/\?a-zA-Z ="\w.\-])+(\?\>)/gm;
  var myNewXML = myXML.replace(foundRegex, '');
  
  return myNewXML;
}

And the return is:

    '<title><line><liste><item></item></liste></line></title>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex that starts with `<?XML` and ends with `?>`
should be given as 
 `<\?\s*XML.*\?>`